# Removing the 'unlimited' option from the pager in listview

Tags: odoo

I want to remove the `unlimited` option of the pager dropdown in `listview`s.
We have 200,000+ contacts in `res_partner` and if someone selects `unlimited` the memory of our 4Gb server fills up and crashes. So therefore we need this (temporary) workaround.

This is what I have now, it works perfectly but I found that `view_list.js` hardcodes the dropdown selection list so I had to repeat this in my override function. OpenErp should make the selection variable, but that hasn't happened yet.  I need more of a second opinion what would be a better solution. After that I want to ask if OpenErp can fix this or propose a more dynamic solution.

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------
* remove unlimited option on listview for res_partner
*---------------------------------------------------------*/

openerp.web_remove_unlimited = function(instance) {

// here you may tweak globals object, if any, and play with on_* or do_* callbacks on them

instance.web.ListView.include({
    load_list: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.dataset.model=='res.partner') {
          this.$pager.find('.oe_list_pager_state')
                .click(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var $this = $(this);

                    var $select = $('<select>')
                        .appendTo($this.empty())
                        .click(function (e) {e.stopPropagation();})
                        .append('<option value="80">80</option>' +
                                '<option value="200">200</option>' +
                                '<option value="500">500</option>' +
                                '<option value="2000">2000</option>')
                        .change(function () {
                            var val = parseInt($select.val(), 10);
                            self._limit = (isNaN(val) ? null : val);
                            self.page = 0;
                            self.reload_content();
                        }).blur(function() {
                            $(this).trigger('change');
                        })
                        .val(self._limit || 'NaN');
                });
        }
        return ret;
    },
 });
};
```

Comment: i really like this idea. a dynamic selection calculated by the count of the records in db would be very nice or/and a changeable selection, too.